# Вызов непонятной ошибки у ActiveRecord (Yii2)

Tags: yii2, activerecord

есть код:

```
$oldGeneralTest = GeneralTestHistory::findOne((int)$value);
$newGeneralTest = new GeneralTestHistory();
$newGeneralTest->test_id = $oldGeneralTest->test_id;
```

Но вызывается ошибка:

**Trying to get property 'test_id' of non-object**

с ссылкой на последнюю строчку.

Если изменить на:

```
$oldGeneralTest = GeneralTestHistory::findOne((int)$value);
$newGeneralTest = new GeneralTestHistory();
$test_id = $oldGeneralTest->test_id;
$newGeneralTest->test_id = $oldGeneralTest->test_id;
```

То выскакивает такая же ошибка, при этом ссылается на предпоследнюю.

При этом, если вывести через var_dump():

```
$oldGeneralTest = GeneralTestHistory::findOne((int)$value);
$newGeneralTest = new GeneralTestHistory();
$test_id = $oldGeneralTest->test_id;
return var_dump($oldGeneralTest->test_id);
$newGeneralTest->test_id = $oldGeneralTest->test_id;
```

Или

```
$oldGeneralTest = GeneralTestHistory::findOne((int)$value);
$newGeneralTest = new GeneralTestHistory();
$test_id = $oldGeneralTest->test_id;
return var_dump($oldGeneralTest->test_id);
$newGeneralTest->test_id = $oldGeneralTest->test_id;
```

То выводит нужное значение и без ошибки.

**$value** - Это переменная цикла foreach. Если заменить на число самому, то все работает как нужно.

Вопрос. В чем магия?

Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @AlMr И правда была проблема в этом. Оформите ответ, зачту за правильный т.к.  помог выяснить проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очевидно что в какой то момент в переменной `$oldGeneralTest` у Вас оказывается `null` - поэтому и возникает ошибка. Введите проверку перед последней строкой на пустоту внутри этой переменной